# Login failure with error 18456 using Windows Groups

Tags: sql-server

I have an application using EF connecting to an SQL Server 2008 Express database and using Windows authentication.

If I add a login for the specific user, it connects successfully. If I add the user to a new Security Group in Active Directory and create a login for that group, connection to the database fails. The error log says:

```
2015-05-29 15:45:53.59 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2015-05-29 15:45:53.59 Logon       Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\test'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 192.168.x.y]
```

I've tried setting a default database for the login and giving it permissions on the master database, but can't get it to work.

I don't really know how to debug it any further.

Comment: I think you'll need to create a mapping from the AD user to a database user...eg create user...from login...

Comment: @David: But suggested best practice seems to be to use AD groups...

Comment: Yes, but you still need to create mappings from the AD groups once you're *in* SQL Server...Take a look at this from dba.stackexchange.com and I think it will give you a good push: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-do-i-assign-an-entire-active-directory-group-security-access-in-sql-server-2